# trying to navigate to anther screen when clicking on a marker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

```js
import React from 'react';
import { MapView } from 'expo';
import db from '../db';
import { createRouter, NavigationProvider, StackNavigation } from '@expo/ex-navigation';
import selectedPhototag from '../screens/selectedPhototag';
import { StackNavigator, NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

const nav = StackNavigator({
  phototag: {
    screen: selectedPhototag,
  },
});

export default class MapScreen extends React.Component {
  state = {
    markers: [],
  };
  componentWillMount() {
    db.child('phototags').once('value').then(photoTags => {
      let dataArray = [];
      for (var key in photoTags.val()) {
        dataArray.push(photoTags.val()[key]);
      }
      this.setState({ markers: dataArray }, () => {
        // console.log('[MapScreen] data', this.state.markers);
      });
    });
  }

  goTophototags() {
    NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: nav.phototag });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <MapView
        provider={MapView.PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
        initialRegion={{
          latitude: 40.750355960509054,
          longitude: -73.97669815393424,
          latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
          longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
        }}>
        {this.state.markers.map((marker, i) =>
          <MapView.Marker
            key={i}
            coordinate={{
              latitude: marker.locationLat,
              longitude: marker.locationLong,
            }}
            title={marker.description}
            onPress={this.goTophototags}
          />
        )}
      </MapView>
    );
  }
}
```

I am trying to navigate to the selectedPhototag screen when one clicks on a marker currently nothing happens on a click the navigation for the rest of the app uses a belt in nav bar so nit sure if I can use those methods, I also want to pass the marker object to the new screen, the app is being made using  Expo react Native

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1, bind it first:

```js
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.goTophototags = this.goTophototags.bind(this);
}
```

2, this case you can call props.navigation.navigate directly:

```js
goTophototags() {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('phototag');
}
```

Comment: nope still nothing also I don't understand why that would work

Comment: for why use `bind`, read it here https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html

Comment: for `props.navigation.navigate` with string, it's how `StackNavigator` works. https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/nesting#Nesting-a-Navigator-in-a-screen

Comment: only if it was passed into the component as props. and the this binding shouldn't make a difference here as it is all in the same context if I am not mistaken?

Comment: Even you choose the way `NavigationActions.navigate`, you have to dispatch it with `props.navigation`... https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/navigation-actions

Comment: for why `onPress={this.goTophototags}` loss the context of `this`, my first link gives a full detail. please have a read on it

Comment: I got it working you were right i just needed to understand the navigator props better from my other screens